# how to measure distance between center of objects - openCV?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have the following code that extracts and "tracks" black objects within a video file or webcam stream.  I am new to Python and CV and am struggling to understand how to extract the center points of the tracked objects for comparison.

Code:

```
#for this demo the only colour we are interested in is black or near black
#remember open cv uses BGR not RGB
groupColorLower = np.array([0,0,0], dtype = "uint8")
groupColorUpper = np.array([179,179,179], dtype ="uint8")

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", required=True,
    help="path to the input video file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

######### Reading input video or opening webcam#########

# if a video path was not supplied, grab the reference
# to the webcam
if not args.get("video", False):
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# otherwise, load the video
else:
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])

######### Finished Reading input video or opening webcam#########

# keep looping
while True:

    # grab the current frame
    (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()

    # if we are viewing a video and we did not grab a
    # frame, then we have reached the end of the video
    if args.get("video") and not grabbed:
        break

    # determine which pixels fall within the black boundaries
    # and then blur the binary image 
    blue = cv2.inRange(frame, groupColorLower, groupColorUpper)
    blue = cv2.GaussianBlur(blue, (3, 3), 0)

    # find contours in the image
    (_, contours1, _) = cv2.findContours(blue.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    #lets try to sort contours1 left to right
    (contours1, _) = contours.sort_contours(contours1)

    if len(contours1) > 0:
    #now lets extract the center point of the left most contour
        fixedPoint = cv2.moments(contours1[0])
        fixedPointX = int (fixedPoint["m10"] / fixedPoint["m00"])
        fixedPointY = int (fixedPoint["m01"] / fixedPoint["m00"])
        #lets draw a white dot in left most object
        cv2.circle(frame, (fixedPointX, fixedPointY), 7, (255,255,255), -1)

    #lets use the nearest to fixedPoint as anchor (left most [1] where [0] is fixedPoint
    if len(contours1) > 1:
                # sort the contours so we can iterate over them
        cnt2 = sorted([(c, cv2.boundingRect(c)[0]) for c in contours1], key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)

        #draw boxes around all objects we are tracking
        for (c, _) in cnt2:
            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)

            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y +h), (255, 255, 0), 4)

            M = cv2.moments(c)
            cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
            cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
            # draw a dot in center of the black object on the image
            cv2.circle(frame, (cX, cY), 7, (100, 100, 100), -1)
            centre.append((int(M["m10"]/M["m00"]), int(M["m01"]/M["m00"])))
```

What I would like to be able to do is print the distance (in pixels) between the objects as they are found but I am not sure how to access this data.

The fixed point calculation works as I assume the left most object can be hard coded, but I need to get the coords for any other objects located.

The code currently loops over each black object and places a dot in the center of it.

Thanks for any help offered:

andy

Comment: try (L2) norm of center1-center2

Comment: maybe you would have a 2d array with 3 channel float data (3d points) or a 2d array with single channel distance values (16-64 bit) (depth map)

Comment: Can you give an example of this please? I am struggling to get to a stage where I can build the array you describe.

Comment: sorry, I commented to the wrong question :D ... so your question is about how to compute the center of the contours? I thought you already had them and wanted to comput the distance...

Comment: I want to calculate the distance between the center of each object detected (pixels is fine).

Comment: so it is enough to tell you how to measure pixel distance? or do you want to know how to compute object centers?

Comment: if you have a set of points, the center could be the center of gravity which is the mean average in each dimension.

Comment: the distance between two points is the L2 norm of the difference vector which is sqrt((p1.x-p2.x)^2 + (p1.y-p2.y)^2) for 2d points.

Comment: OK and how do I obtain and iterate through the p1x and p2x etc for each object detected in the contours above

Comment: each contour is a set of points but for python I can't tell you how to access the single points.